# DB2 SQL : Combine two queries and select max of one aggregate column

Tags: sql, db2

I have two queries (example version)-

Query A:

```
select 
  col1 as COL1,
  col2 as COL2,
  sum(col3) as COL3
from table1 join table11 ..
group by col1, col2;
```

Query B:

```
select 
  col1 as COL1,
  col2 as COL2,
  count(col3) as COL3
from table2
group by col1, col2;
```

I want to join both of them and have output like below. Tried this

```
select A.COL1, A.COL2, greatest(A.COL3, B.COL3)
from (query A) A
UNION (query B) B
```

but getting the error

> `SQL0104N An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "col2) B".
>   Expected tokens may include: "JOIN <joined_table>". 
>   SQLSTATE=42601`

Both the queries individually are running fine, but when combined using UNION like above, it is giving error.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: This is not what union does.... you want a join.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a *join*, not a *union*:

```
select A.COL1, A.COL2, greatest(A.COL3, B.COL3)
from (query A) A
join (query B) B on A.COL1 = B.COL1 and A.COL2 = B.COL2
```

Depending on your needs, you may need a `left join`, `right join` or `full outer join` instead of an inner `join`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with A as  
 (
 select 
 col1 as COL1,
 col2 as COL2,
 sum(col3) as COL3
 from table1 join table11 ..
 group by col1, col2
 ),
 B as
 (
 select 
 col1 as COL1,
 col2 as COL2,
 count(col3) as COL3
 from table2
 group by col1, col2
 ) 

 select ifnull(A.COL1, B.COL1) as COL1, ifnull(A.COL2, B.COL2) as COL2,
 greatest(ifnull(A.COL3, 0), ifnull(B.COL3, 0)) as great
 from A full outer join B on A.COL1 = B.COL1 and A.COL2 = B.COL2
```